# Spring inject mocked Bean

Tags: java, spring, validation

I created a validation constraint depending on a repository.

```
public class PersonValidator implements ConstraintValidator {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Override
    public void initialize(PersonValidator personValidator) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Person person, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return null != repository.findByName(person.getName());
    }
}
```

Testing the validator itself is easy by mocking the `PersonValidator` but I want to test the integration with the validator to check the validation message for example.

```
public class PersonValidatorTest {

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    @Test
    public void integration() {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("person");

        Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(person);
        Assert.assertEquals(0, constraintViolations.size());
    }
}
```

I don't know how to inject a `PersonValidator` inside the `Validator` with the mocked repository.

Comment: 1) Are you using a mocking framwork? 2) Please show us `Validator` as well if you've created it, or tell us what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running test with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner, and create a mock repository bean and annotate with spring's @Primary annotation or mark as primary in bean definition for test to autowire mock repository.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/context.xml", "/test-context.xml"})
public class PersonValidatorTest {

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;
....
```

You can create mock repository using mockito factory bean as below

```
public class MockitoFactoryBean<T> implements FactoryBean<T> {
    private Class<T> classToBeMocked;

    public MockitoFactoryBean(Class<T> classToBeMocked) {
        this.classToBeMocked = classToBeMocked;
    }

    @Override
    public T getObject() throws Exception {
        return Mockito.mock(classToBeMocked);
    }
....
```

and then create spring's context file 'test-context.xml' for test repository

```
<bean id="mockRepository" primary="true" class="com.test.mock.MockitoFactoryBean">
    <constructor-arg value="com....PersonRepository"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "context.xml")
public class PersonValidatorTest {

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer setter injection, which makes injecting mocks simple during tests.

Or you can also use reflection based injection with a [spring util class](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M2/api/org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.html).